# Images not loaded on mobile when lazy loading

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I am using the LazyLoad JavaScript library (https://github.com/verlok/lazyload). On my homepage, I have a button, when clicking that button, I open a panel containing  small .svg icons where the user can select them, it functions as a filter. 
The lazy loading works perfectly on my laptop browser and it saves me immense amount of loading time. However, when on mobile, the images are not loading at all. (when emulating a mobile device in my laptop browser, it also works perfectly). But on a "real" mobile device, It looks like this:
[image: lazy loading on mobile]

The code looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="interests" id="interest-filter">
<span class="home-close">X</span>
<span id="interest-amount"><?=lang("home_filter_what")?></span>
<ul class="drop-down" id="mobile-dropdown">
<?php
     foreach ($interests as $value){
         echo '<li class="mob-list">';
         echo '<img data-src="' . base_url() . 'design/img/interesses/grey/' . $value->name_grey . '" alt="' . pathinfo($value->name, PATHINFO_FILENAME). '" data-id="' . $value->interest_id . '" title="' . $this->namemanager->getInterestName($value->interest_id) . '" class="lazy"/>';
         echo '<span class="mob-span">' . $this->namemanager->getInterestName($value->interest_id) . '</span>';
          echo '</li>';
     }
?>
</ul>
```

An element would look like this in the outputted HTML:

```
<li class="mob-list"><img src="https://www.abc.be/design/img/interesses/grey/interesse-administratie-grey.svg" alt="interesse-administratie" data-id="1" title="Administratie"><span class="mob-span">Administratie</span></li>
```

**EDIT:** I noticed that when I open the website in an incognito browser on my phone that it does work. Why is this happening? The images haven't changed since a long time?

**EDIT2:** I have tried adding a random query string to the end of the image URL to force reload the image, this does not work either, result is still the same. The url is something like eg: https://www.abc.be/design/img/interesses/grey/interesse-administratie-grey.svg?178489181

Comment: What have you tried already? Does it work without that lib?
Do the SVG files load fine on mobile if accessed directly?

btw, this link doesn't seem to work: https://www.abc.be/design/img/interesses/grey/interesse-administratie-grey.svg

Comment: Hello @targumon It works without the library yes, but I have just noticed that when I open it in incognito on mobile that it does work. So it seems to be a caching issue or i don't know what it is? How do I go about this, since the images haven't changed in a very long time, and I would have expected LazyLoad to just load in the images like it does on my laptop browser? As for the URL, it's indeed a dummy url, i'm not comfortable sharing the URL of the website on here.

Comment: did you test on several phones, or only one ? Enabling incognito mode looks like a client side config problem. Is svg correctly registered as mime type on your server ?

Comment: I have tested on 3 android phone and 1 iPhone. The ones where it worked on are the ones who never visted our site before, all the other ones have visited the site before, and thus the image is not loading at all. 
This means that the image is still cached or something and it would not show? As a test I tried adding ?123456 at the end of the image url to force reload it, but it still does not work.

Comment: I have used the website https://htmlstrip.com/mime-file-type-checker to check the mime type of the image files, it all comes back as "image/svg" so I think it is correct

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. So we ruled out the lazy load lib. Now get back to your images: I STILL can't access that svg (interesse-administratie-grey.svg) I get "This site can’t provide a secure connection". What is that domain (abc.be)? Are you actually on intra-net? This will explain why your laptop (probably connected to the office network) can access those SVG files, while the device (probably connected to some mobile provider) can not.